# How to delete a line of string in a text file - Java

Tags: java, string, file-handling, filewriter

I used a filewriter class to write my inputs into a text file. Is there a way I can delete a line in the txt file created?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            FileWriter f = new FileWriter("output.txt", false);
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){ 
                System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
                f.write(x+1 + " " + read.nextLine() + '\n');
            }
            f.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The strings written in the file is [image]

what if I want to remove 2 hello from the contents of the file? What should I do?

Comment: You read in the file, and write out a new file, except for the parts you want to 'delete'.

Comment: You can read the file into a List<String>, then remove the 2nd entry of the list. Then write the list back into the same file overwriting it.

Comment: Please explain what difficulty you're having doing this.